# breadcrumbs overlapping on child components content

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have breadcrumbs and child components in a parent component. bread crumbs is not visible in the initial page load. child components content will be displayed. on click in the child component, bread crumbs is visible, but on top of child component content. My requirement is when bootstrap is visible, child component should be visible and there should not be any overlap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="breadCrumbs?.length>0">
        <div class="col">
            <nav aria-label='breadcrumb' class="breadcrumb-fixed">
                <ol class='breadcrumb'>
                    <li *ngFor='let breadcrumb of breadCrumbs'>
                        <a (click)="handleBreadCrumb()">{{ breadcrumb.label}}</a>

                    </li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            //child components goes here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

breadcrumb-fixed css code:

```
breadcrumb-fixed {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: a minimal stackblitz repro would help more. Thanks.

Comment: Cannot use transient scratch-pad sites. If the link breaks eventually answer breaks and not useful for the community.

Comment: when show the breadcrum, set a margin to de div where is the child component `[style.margin]="showBreadcrum?'2rem':null`